# Share favorites in Firefox using Bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, firefox

I'm using BootCamp to install Windows 7 on my Mac. On both OS I'm using Firefox 6. Is there an easy way to automatically share the favorites in both OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Firefox 4 or higher, you can use [Firefox's built-in sync capabilities](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/sync/) to keep multiple instances of Firefox in sync across different operating systems and machines.

[C|Net has a nice video that shows you how to set it up.](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20007087-285/how-to-set-up-firefox-sync-video/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the [Xmarks service](http://www.xmarks.com/). It can sync between multiple browsers: Firefox, Chrome and even Safari in Mac.